# Cross account IAM roles for Kubernetes service account - s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-s3, roles, service-accounts

Hey im trying to cross account access for a role. **i have 2 accounts: prod and non-prod**.
and **bucket in prod account**, which im trying to write files to there from a non-prod role which is used as a service account in k8s cluster.

**in prod account i configured:**
a role with the following policy(read write access to the bucket):

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "ListObjectsInBucket",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:ListBucket"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::test2"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Sid": "AllObjectActions",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "s3:*Object",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::test2/*"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

and the following trust:

```
{


"Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::non-prod-AccountID:role/name-of-the-non-prod-role"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Condition": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

**in non prod i configured:**

a role with the following policy:

```
   {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::prod-Account-ID:role/prod-role-name"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Condition": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

and trust as follows:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::non-prod-accountID:oidc-provider/oidc.eks.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/id/1111111111111111111"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "oidc.eks.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/id/1111111111111111111:sub": 
            "system:serviceaccount:name-space:name-of-the-service-account"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

serviceAccount annotation is:

```
annotations: 
eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn: arn:aws:iam::non-prod-AccountID:role/non-prod-role-name
```

when running the command from inside the pod with the service account of the role in non-prod:

```
aws s3 cp hello.txt s3://test2/hello.txt
```

im having:

```
upload failed: ./hello.txt to s3://test2/hello.txt An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied
```

by the way the cluster is in another account (devops account) if its related, surely added OIDC provider identity to both non-prod and prod accounts as identity provider.

Comment: Hi talms1 welcome to SO. You didn't include the annotation for your `ServiceAccount` in your question. I would also be interested in knowing if you changed the `Action` to not have leading a wildcard, does it start to work? Finally, don't overlook the power of `aws --debug s3 cp` in order to see what awscli thinks is going on. Good luck

Comment: my serviceAccount annotation is:
 annotations:
    # eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn: arn:aws:iam::non-prod-AccountID:role/non-prod-role-name.

you mean the action of the s3 policy? its not matter, i can even put s3FullAcess policy, and still have the same error.

Comment: I think your "BTW" stanza is the whole problem: you haven't included the "devops" account in any of those trust relationships. You can confirm this by yourself by [manually running `sts assume-role-with-web-identity`](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/sts/assume-role-with-web-identity.html) using `--web-identity-token "$(cat /var/run/secrets/eks.amazonaws.com/serviceaccount/token)"`

Comment: @talms1, did you figure out the solution? I'm stuck at the same

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting the error `An error occurred (InvalidIdentityToken) when calling the AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity operation: No OpenIDConnect provider found in your account for $oidc_url` when trying to cross-account assume roles, but you can assume roles in your cluster account normally, here's some points:

**EKS ACCOUNT**

1. Create a ServiceAccount

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: $sa_name
  namespace: $eks_ns
  annotations:
    eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn: arn:aws:iam::$resource_account_id:role/$role_name
```

2. Annotate your deployment

```
spec.template.spec:
  serviceAccountName: $sa_name
```

3. Get info about your cluster OIDC Provider

```
aws iam get-open-id-connect-provider --open-id-connect-provider-arn arn:aws:iam::$eks_cluster_account_id:oidc-provider/$oidc_provider
```

3.1. The output will be like:

```
{
    "Url": "...",
    "ClientIDList": ["..."],
    "ThumbprintList": ["..."],
    "CreateDate": "...",
    "Tags": [...]
}
```

3.2. Take note of the outputs (*Url* and *ThumbprintList* specially)

**RESOURCE ACCOUNT**

1. Add the provider (if you don`t have it already), using the output from your cluster account

```
aws iam create-open-id-connect-provider --url $oidc_url --client-id-list sts.amazonaws.com --thumbprint-list $oidc_thumbprint
```

This should be enought to the mentioned error stop. If you now get `An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity operation: Not authorized to perform sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity`, you're problably using the *$eks_cluster_account_id* on Principal.Federated, instead of *$resource_account_id* created on the previous step. So, make sure you're using the ARN from the IP that is assigned to the resource account, not the cluster account.

2. Create a role and a policy to access your resources with following trusted entities policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::$resource_account_id:oidc-provider/$oidc_provider"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity"
        }
    ]
}
```

Also, there's no need to have two roles. One is enough.